# In App Billing Item Unavailable User is not eligible to purches this item

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am going through a problem while doing inapp android purchases. At Starting i m face a problem

**Application Error**

[image: Application Error]

that is solved by me on upload an item on my Google play Console And now i m got Another problem

**Item Unavailable**

[image: Item Unavailable]

Thanks For help

Answer (score 0):

Add the account you are using as a tester account to the app by going to **Settings > License Testing > Gmail accounts with testing access** and adding your email address there.